# How to make 2 grid columns the same size, but as narrow as the largest element in them

Tags: css, css-grid

I want 3 columns. col 1 and 3 should be the same size and col 2 in the middle should take as much space as possible.

**What I tried:**

```css
grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;  // This way, col 2 tries to take as little space as possible
grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto; // This way, col 1 and 3 are not the same size
```

Everything needs to stay dynamic the outer columns may contain Links/Styled Buttons, groups of SVGs, and Images of a fixed width, which would usually be the widest element. And as I said the outer columns should be as small as possible without forcing linebreaks.

I made a Snippet, that should illustrate the problem pretty well, if you expand it.

```css
.container1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  gap: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.container2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.item {
  justify-self: center;
  padding: .2rem;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.item2 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="item item1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="item item2">Column 2<br>If I had an input field here<br>I would want it as wide as possible<br>This Element is the only one with width:100%;<br> But it still stays narrow</div>
  <div class="item item3">Column 3</div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="item item1">Column 1<br>This is where this column needs to be</div>
  <div class="item item2">Column 2<br>Now it is wide :)<br>But it is off center :/</div>
  <div class="item item3">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would the two outer columns' width be? As small as possible? As small as possible with a minimum value? An exact percentage of their parent's? Please provide more details, including your HTML as well. We can't and don't want to guess what the content would be.

Comment: @InSync I added the info you requested. Hope that helps to clarify.

Comment: There is to my knowledge, no css method to make the 2 columns the same width. You will need javascript I suspect.